# Upgrading Node on an Azure website?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to run some pre deployment tasks (unit tests etc) with NPM on an Azure website, however the version of node on the VM is v0.10.32, the current version of node is v4.2.4.

I have non administrative access to the command line via the SCM website, no RDP etc.

Is there any way to upgrade?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can specify the version of node that the app is running on using the package.json file. Add:

```
"engines":{"node":version}
```

e.g.:

```
"engines":{"node": "0.12.x"},
```

More info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/

Comment: This is for running NPM tasks though, will this still work?

Comment: I used that on my last project. Then  when I called node -v it reported the correct node version number.

Comment: Indeed, this should work. Other option is to change the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` App Setting in the Azure Portal.

Comment: specifying the node version using the package.json file does not seem to work when deploying through VSTS. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Changing the `engine` version in `package.json` has absolutely no effect for me. When the container boots up it says `NodeJS Version : v12.19.0` no matter what I set in `engine`. Setting `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `14` or `v14` also has no effect.

Answer (score 31):

Ensure the Azure Web App has the node version you want.

1. Go to yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net
2. Choose Debug Console (PowerShell or CMD)
3. Navigate to `D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`
4. Run `dir` to see the available nodejs versions.

For instance, if there is a directory named `6.3.0`, then you can use it.

```
// App Setting
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 6.3.0  

// package.json
engines":{"node": "6.3.0"}
```

Comment: This was helpful they didn't have 6.10.1 when I tried to upgrade but they had 6.10.0

Comment: This worked for me as of 11/3/2017 without the need for a iisnode.yml file.

Comment: ... for a node.js angular app. I used VSTS for both the git repository, build and release. The build is using Visual Studio 2017 hosted, npm to install angular and node, command line for the ng build. It is based on the npm with Gulp VSTS build template. The release just grabs the artifact and pushes it to Azure.

Comment: Works 2 years later ... Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I wish I could upvote this many times.

Answer (score 14):

2017 update. All above didn't work for me in.

I changed:

```
// package.json
engines":{"node": "8.0.0"}
```

and then I added app settings value

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" value="8.0.0" />
</appSettings>
```

I restarted an app million times, and **the solution** was to change iisnode.yml

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.0.0\node.exe"
```

That's it. I hope it will help someone.

## Update

Just to clarify things: I'm talking about App Service
[image: App Service Image]

And if you ftp to your App you will see **iisnode.yml** here:

[image: iisnode.yml on ftp]

Comment: So the accepted answer didn't work? If so, I'll change yours to the accepted one.

Comment: @JMK no, it didn't work for me. Maybe they changed stuff since that time, I'm not sure. But other settings didn't change anything until I changed iisnode.yml. Maybe that happens because I didn't specify node version initially so it defaulted to v0.10 which not supported by many plugins as of today.

Comment: @PavelKovalev Where did you find iisnode.yml? I haven't found a copy of it that I'm allowed to edit without admin privileges.

Comment: @StephenGTuggy I updated my answer and added a few pictures. So you have to FTP to your App Service so you can see  iisnode.yml

Comment: iisnode.yml is an optional file that overrides settings from your web.config file. this means that because you have it, it must point to the correct node executable but for everyone else it's not necessarily the correct answer.

https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/iisnode.yml

Comment: ohh....it was life saver.... got tired of all above solution and then scrolled down here.....tha iisnode.yml change worked......:)

Answer (score 11):

Changing NodeJs Version in Azure Portal

Navigate to your web app in azure portal
Click on Application settings in Settings blade.
You can include WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION as key and  version of nodejs you want as value in app settings.

Example: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 8.0.0

[image]

Comment: thankyou my friend!! obrigado amigo ! here brazilian!

Comment: And make sure the version you set it to is supported. You can get the list of versions by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515422/10893

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was neither to set the `engine` version in `package.json`, nor to set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`, but to use the [`az` command line as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux):

```sh
az webapp config set \
  --resource-group <resource-group-name> \
  --name <app-name> \
  --linux-fx-version "NODE|14-lts"
```