# Upgrading Node.js version on an Azure Linux Web App?

Tags: node.js, linux, azure-web-app-service

I've just created an Azure Linux Web App (preview) following this link:

- [Create an Azure web app running on Linux](http://Create%20an%20Azure%20web%20app%20running%20on%20Linux)

I've developped a [koajs](http://koajs.com/) backend that requires node v7.6.0 or higher.

Also I've read this SO Post: [Upgrading Node on an Azure website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746480/upgrading-node-on-an-azure-website) but it is related to Azure Windows Web App using [iis_node](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode).

So far, I tried to install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/) from the bash kudu console:
`https://{mysitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`
But it did not work

So now my guess is that when I choose the Node.js version from the azure portal, Azure selects a specific built-in docker image. Because there is no image for Node.js v7.6.0 or higher I need to create my own image ?

Is there anyway to get the latest docker image config for node.js from the portal or do I need to create one from scratch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure WebApp on Linux is a Docker container, according to the offical document [`Using a custom Docker image for Azure Web App on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image), you can set a custom Docker image which includes Node.js higher version for a web app or using a node offical higer version image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Greate THanks, I am gonna try this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Node.js versions available on the Linux platform are: `4.4.7, 4.5.0, 6.2.2, 6.6.0, 6.9.3, 6.10.3`. I would recommend you switch to use Azure Windows Web App which enables you to upgrade the Node.js runtime to `v7.6.0` or higher (`7.7.4, 8.0.0, 8.1.4`).

Comment: Yeah this is good approach but I just wanted to test Linux webapp :-)