# Issue while trying to update nodejs version in azure app. Unable to perform build for the app in azure

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I deployed my angular app to azure which uses ASP.NET backend and it was working fine. I updated my angular app from version 5.1 to 6.1 and installed angularcli version 6.2.5. For this version to work, my node version in azure should be 8.9 or greater. So I am trying to update nodejs for my appsevice in azure by following the steps mentioned in the link [Upgrading Node on an Azure website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746480/upgrading-node-on-an-azure-website). I made both the changes mentioned below as explained in the link and I don't have any iisnode.yml file.

```
// Added App Setting in the 'Application Settings' section of my app service
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 8.9.4  

// Added engines field in the package.json file in my angular app 
engines":{"node": "8.9.4"}
```

The steps for the build process are shown in the pics attached
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The 'build app' step fails with the error shown below. I don't understand why it still uses node version 6.9.1. Should I add any other steps here to get it working or make any other changes? Please help me with this issue

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Task "Node.js tool installer" to your pipeline to install the suitable node version

[image]