# Having trouble deploying Angular app to azure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy my angular app to azure.

I use vs code and I am using the extension "Azure App Service".

I have followed this guide completely: https://www.webcodegeeks.com/javascript/angular-js/deploy-angular-app-visual-studio-azure/

And when I finished the guide I was able to deploy the Angular app. But i just recieve the image below when i visit my webpage:

[image]

This is the first time i use azure so i have no idea on what to do.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746480/upgrading-node-on-an-azure-website

Comment: Cant see why this is down voted - i get it's a partial duplicate but i my problem is still not solved. I have tried what is @Marc suggested but still get the same screen as shown above. I have managed to upgrade to the correct version of node using the approach from the link. I don't know if there is any other way to deploy an angular app using azure since this does not work :)

Answer (score 0):

Search your package.json for the following entry:

```
"engines":{"node": "10.13.0"}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the one linked to in comments. Best to just vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, No it is not a duplicate. I have solved the problem now and the duplicate is not the solution. Remove the duplicate and i'll post the solution.