# NodeJs on Azure app service using ASP.NET Core NodeServices does not execute

Tags: node.js, azure, asp.net-core

I have a site on Azure App Service which uses node js to print pdf files.

The site is built on asp.net core and uses `NodeServices` to call phantomjs library which will be used to convert html page to pdf.

I am using the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddNodeServices();
}
```

And use the below code to invoke the nodejs file:

```
var result = await _nodeServices.InvokeAsync<bool>("./NodeJs/createPdf.js", pageUrl);
```

My project solution does contain `package.json` file as well and it has required dependencies. The solution does work fine on my local machine.

On azure I have set the nodejs version to be the maximum available in the [Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952962/1158845):

```
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
    "value": "10.15.2"
  },
```

When executing this on app services I get the following error:

```
[2019-05-14 12:15:12 ERR] Connection id "0HLMOCN6RLHIU", Request id "0HLMOCN6RLHIU:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Cannot find module 'phantom'
Error: Cannot find module 'phantom'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\NodeJs\createPdf.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExportAsync[T](NodeInvocationInfo invocationInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.InvokeExportAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken, String moduleName, String exportNameOrNull, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at PdfProcessor.Controllers.ProcessToPdfController.Generate(PdfRequestModel model) in d:\a\1\s\PdfProcessor\Controllers\ProcessToPdfController.cs:line 82
   at PdfProcessor.Controllers.ProcessToPdfController.GeneratePdf(String pageUrl) in d:\a\1\s\PdfProcessor\Controllers\ProcessToPdfController.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

The error seems as if npm install has not been run on app services. I have tried with different node versions and restarted app service but still get the same error.

I have also tried deleting `package-lock.json` file and republishing the site, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that the C# runtime cannot find the Node JS dependency `phantom`. From a Node JS perspective, I think it's likely that the dependency isn't installed because Kudu likely doesn't install dependencies in a C# App Service. This would explain why it works on your machine, but not in the cloud. To get it resolved, try following these steps below:

1. Launch the Azure Portal and navigate to your App Service > Select Advanced Tools > Go. This should open Kudu Services in a new tab on your browser.
2. Select Debug Console > PowerShell from the top menu bar
3. Navigate to `site/wwwroot/`. You should see your `package.json` file and a folder called `node_modules`. This folder stores your Node JS dependencies (eg: `phantom`). If the `node_modules` folder is not found, it'll get created with the next step.
4. From the PowerShell prompt, run `npm install`.
5. You should now see the `node_modules` folder if it was not previously present. Inside it, you should find a lot of folders. However, you should see a `phantom` in that folder. This would be success.
6. Restart your App Service and test your function

If you don't have your `package.json` file, it may not be getting published, in which case you have a different issue.